# Regex cuts word if end of string

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to check and capture 2 or x words after and before a target string in a multiline text. The problem is that if the words matched are less than x number of words, then regex cuts off the last word and splits it till x.

For example

```
text = "This is an example /year"
```

if example is the target:

> Matching Data: "is" , "an", "/yea", "r"

If i add random words after /year it matches it correctly.

How could I fix this so that if less than x words exist just stop there or return empty for the rest of the matches?

So it should be

> Matching Data: "is" , "an", "/year", ""

```
def checkWords(target, text, numLeft = 2, numRight = 2)

target = target.compact.map{|x| x.inspect}.join('').gsub(/"/, '')

    regex = ""
    regex += "\\s+{,2}(\\S+)\\s+{,2}" * numLeft
    regex += target
    regex += "\\s+{,2}(\\S+)" * numRight

    pattern = Regexp.new(regex)
    matches = pattern.match(text)

    puts matches.inspect

end
```

Comment: Change `regex += "\\s+{,2}(\\S+)\\s+{,2}" * numLeft` to `regex += "(?:\\S+\\s+){0," + numLeft + "}"`  and `"\\s+{,2}(\\S+)" * numRight` to `"(?:\\s+\\S+){0," + numRight + "}"`. See https://ideone.com/7l7rBW

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if I use this one for example for "London Bridge Station target a year - Permanent" it only matches Bridge Station and not a year which is after target.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes changed it to "(?:(\\S+)\\s+){0,#{numLeft}}"  but it does not capture 2 words. Only 1 before and after. Even if i increase numLeft and numRight. Actually it doesnt even match the right words

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew regex = (?:(\S+)\s+){0,2}target(?:\s+(\S+)){0,2}

Comment: Look [here](http://rubular.com/r/leC6LYKWlZ), it matches `Bridge Station target a year` well. I also keep in mind that your search words can contain any non-whitespace symbols.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Look what happens i try capture the words: http://rubular.com/r/0Oe17RAbPy

Comment: That is expected behavior with repeated capturing groups, once in a quantified group, the value captured in the last iteration is only stored in the group buffer. Use it [like this](http://rubular.com/r/mLQfT2PC1G).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to *capture* the words before and after *target*, you need to set a capturing group around the whole regex parts that match the 0 to 2 occurrences of spaces-non-spaces. Also, you need to allow a minimum bound of `0` - use `{0,2}` (or a more succint `{,2}`) limiting quantifier to make sure you get the context on the left even if it is missing on the right:

```
/((?:\S+\s+){,2})target((?:\s+\S+){,2})/
 ^              ^      ^              ^
```

See [this Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/5sjJOAt8Fw)

If you use `/(?:(\S+)\s+){0,2}target(?:\s+(\S+)){0,2}/`, all captured values but the last one will be lost, i.e. once quantified, repeated capturing groups only store the value captured during the last iteration in the group buffer.

Also note that setting a `{,2}` quantifier on the `+` quantifier makes no sense, `\\s+{,2}` = `\\s+`.